# Changing SKScene causes game lags

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I'm developing a game in iOS Spritekit using Swift. I created a menu and then I'm calling a GameScene appear jerking lags.
But! If I load only game scene everything all right, if I'm load game, and change to another scene, it's causes lags.
I`m tested on iPhone 5 (iOS 8.1.x/8.2 beta) Xcode(6.1.x/6.2 beta). In simulator everything all right
You can see that on this simple code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let kMovementSpeed:CGFloat = 3.8
    var firstX:CGFloat = 0
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake (0.5,0.5)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        addBall()
    }
    func addBall(){
        var ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(30))
        ball.name = "ball"
        ball.fillColor = .redColor()
        ball.position = CGPointMake (-200, 0)
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (circleOfRadius: 30)
        self.addChild(ball)
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var  touch:UITouch!
        touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if ((location.x <= 0) & (location.y <= 0)) {
            firstX = location.x
        }
        else if ((location.x >= 0) & (location.y <= 0)) {
            var ball = self.childNodeWithName("ball") as SKShapeNode
            ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 113))
        }
        else if ((location.x <= 0) & (location.y >= 0)) {
            var ball = self.childNodeWithName("ball") as SKShapeNode
            ball.removeAllActions()
            var game:GameScene!
            self.removeAllActions()
            var moveSequence = SKAction.runBlock({
                game = GameScene(size:(self.view?.frame.size)!)
                game.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            })
            self.runAction(moveSequence, completion: {
                self.view?.presentScene(game)
                return
            })
        }
    }
    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if ((location.x <= 0) & (location.y <= 0)) {
                var ball = self.childNodeWithName("ball") as SKShapeNode
                let ySpeed = ball.physicsBody?.velocity.dy
                ball.physicsBody?.velocity.dx =   kMovementSpeed * (location.x - firstX)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

upper-left corner - represent scene.
 
bottom left corner - simple joystick.
 
bottom-right corner - jump.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how is this translated to `Swift`, since I'm an `Objective-C` type of guy, but I would suggest to add an 'implementation' of `dealloc`, with an `NSLog` statement, to make sure that your 'old' scene you is indeed deallocated when switching to a new scene. I would suggest calling it on each scene, just for debugging purposes, and when done, remove it. `-(void) dealloc{NSLog(@"dealloc: %@", self);}`

Comment: are you saying that creating a new GameScene while your game is running causes the game to lag?  Does it just lag for a second, or is it consistently laggy after that point?

Comment: No, I'm saying that maybe he has some sort of memory leak in his main menu scene and that is why when you he's calling his game scene from the main menu he have lags, that otherwise he doesn't have. If `dealloc` gets called it will rule this out.

Comment: Hamobi, consistently laggy after point.

Comment: Have you tried what I've suggested mate?

Comment: yes, tried. Scene is deallocated. Its very simple scene.The truth I tried many ways...helps only sleep(2) or >2 in didMoveToView implementation, but it`s bad way. I think trouble in dispatch